# Catenoid which intersects a torus along a circle centered at the origin in the plane $z=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Catenoid: $C(\theta,u)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $u$ $\in$ $ℝ$

$$x=\left(R-r\right)\cosh\left(u\right)\cos t $$
$$y=\left(R-r\right)\cosh\left(u\right)\sin t $$
$$z=pu$$

Torus: $T(\theta,u)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $u$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$

$$x=(R+r\cos\left(u\right))\cos \theta $$
$$y=(R+r\cos\left(u\right))\sin \theta $$
$$z=r\sin u$$

**What must the value of $p$ be in order for the two surfaces to intersect only along a circle in the $z=0$ plane?**

Slice the catenoid and the torus simultaneously with a plane containing the $z$-axis.

The resultant cross section is comprised of two opposite-facing catenaries as well as two circles, each circle tangent to its corresponding catenary.

Choose either circle and consider the point at which it intersects the catenary that it is tangent to.

Denote this intersection point $I$.

Our goal is to find out what $p$ must be in order for the curvature of the circle at $I$ to be equal to the curvature of the catenary at $I$.

WLOG I'll provide the parametric equation for the catenary which resides in quadrants 1 and 4:

$$\left(\left(R-r\right)\cosh t,pt\right)$$

Let $k$ denote the curvature of this catenoid at $t=0$

Given that the circle is of radius $r$, its curvature at any point is $1/r$

Setting the curvatures equal to one another, we get

$$k=1/r$$

So now all I need is a closed-form expression for $k$ in terms of $p$, $R$ and $r$, and then I'll be able to solve for $p$ in terms of $R$ and $r$.

The $k$ value I got is $\frac{R-r}{p^2}$

[Desmos seems to agree](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nysptc8xpi) that $p≥\sqrt{r(R-r)}$ are the $p$ values we're after

[Here in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kjocthj89d) I've graphed the catenoid and the torus, and by playing around with the $p$ value you can confirm for yourself that the $p$ values such that $p≥\sqrt{r(R-r)}$ do indeed work.

Here are the steps to the calculation of the curvature of the catenary

1. $$f\left(t\right)=\left(\left(R-r\right)\cosh t,pt\right)$$
2. $$\left|f'\left(t\right)\right|=\sqrt{p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t}$$
3. Unit tangent $\equiv T=\left(\frac{\left(R-r\right)\sinh t}{\sqrt{p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t}},\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t}}\right)$
4. $$\frac{dT}{dt}=\left(\frac{p^{2}\left(R-r\right)\cosh t}{\left(p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}},\frac{-p\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh\left(t\right)\cosh\left(t\right)}{\left(p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)$$
5. $$\left|\frac{dT}{dt}\right|=\frac{p\left(R-r\right)\cosh t}{\left(p^{2}+\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sqrt{\left(R-r\right)^{2}\sinh^{2}t+p^{2}}$$

---

#### The general case

Suppose that we modify the surfaces in the following way

Catenoid: $C(\theta,u)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $u$ $\in$ $ℝ$

$$x=\left(a-r\right)\cosh\left(u\right)\cos t $$
$$y=\left(b-r\right)\cosh\left(u\right)\sin t $$
$$z=pu$$

Torus: $T(\theta,u)=(x,y,z)$, $\theta$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$, $u$ $\in$ $[0,2\pi)$

$$x=(a+r\cos\left(u\right))\cos \theta $$
$$y=(b+r\cos\left(u\right))\sin \theta $$
$$z=r\sin u$$

**What must the value of $p$ be in order for the two surfaces to intersect only along an ellipse in the $z=0$ plane?**

The procedure to solve this problem is very similar to the process used in the special case

The answer is $p≥\sqrt{r(c-r)}$ where $c=\max(a,b)$

[Here is a graph in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mgzfenh0yf) of the catenoid and the torus.

Comment: The denominator in your curvature expression for the catenary should be $p^{\color{red}2}$, not $p^3$.

Comment: @user170231 thanks. I fixed it. I'm going to edit the post so as to include the step-by-step calculation so that the point at which I wrote the wrong exponent can be identified

Comment: There's at least one mistake in step 4, the first component of $\frac{dT}{dt}$ appears to be missing a factor of $p^2$ in the numerator.